# Adding a send-email script to a pingall bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am currently trying to make a simple script/tool in order to ping and monitor the network for all the IP Cameras in the company. So i created iplist.txt and added all the ips into it where each is on a single line. The script will ping all the list and then prints "up" or "down" according to the ping result.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Program name: pingall.sh
date
cat /home/wade/iplist.txt |  while read output
do
    ping -c 1 "$output" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "node $output is up" 
    else
    echo "node $output is down"
    fi
done
```

What I am trying to do now is to add a send email script with the output to an email. All the email ports (465,993,587,25 ... etc) are open. So how can I add a sendmail or mail script that can send the output to a gmail or a non gmail (dovecot probably) email address?

running `./pingall.sh > report.txt` would probably be the attachment or the content. I will probably add this to a crond after it's done.

Comment: You can generally send anything from cli by doing `mail -s "subject" "recipient"`...

Comment: related question : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/can-i-set-up-system-mail-to-use-an-external-smtp-server

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer to this, in order to do so you first need to install the ssmtp package:

In Debian Based Systems:

```
apt-get install ssmtp
```

In Arch Linux

```
pacman -S ssmtp
```

After that you'll need to edit the conf file at /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf with your information: (gmail mail-server's info here is the example)

```
vim /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf


# root is the person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
root=your@email.com

# Here is the gmail configuration (or change it to your private smtp server)
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=your@gmail.com
AuthPass=yourGmailPass
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

For gmail accounts, you will probably get an error message so you need to set the security to low. (instructions will be sent into your inbox after the first attempt)

Now, you need to create a permanent alias for pingall.

First you need to edit the .bashrc file

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add the alias at the end of the file: (depends on your script's location)

```
alias pingall='cd /home/wade && ./pingall.sh'
```

Save and exit and now execute

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Finally, You'll want to automate this daily through cron.daily

if you're using Arch Linux you'll need to install cronie first, otherwise it should be there by default.

```
pacman -S cronie
```

You need to cd into /etc/cron.daily , then create a cron job file "pingall", to add the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pingall >> mail -s "sample subject" samplemail@test.com
```

You can replace vim with any other text editors like nano, vi, gedit as preferred.

At last, you now have an automatic script that pings all the ip cameras daily and email the output to the recipient at the end of the bash script.

(you can also add multiple recipients, just add a comma "," then the next email.

I hope it helps.